# Python 3 not all 1 line functions are lambdas?

Tags: python, function, lambda

For the following 4 functions:

```
def test1(a):
  def result(b):
    return a+b;
  return result

def test2(a):
  return lambda b: a+b

test3 = lambda a : lambda b : a+b

test4 = lambda a : (lambda b : a+b)

print(test1(2)(3))
print(test2(3)(4))
print(test3(5)(6))
print(test4(7)(8))
```

`test1` works fine `test1(a)(b)` returns a+b
`test2` works fine too `test2(a)(b)` returns a+b
but `test3` and `test4` give a syntax error `undefined variable a`

why can the interpreter find a in test1 and 2 but not in 3 or 4?
is there a way to write the test function as a lambda?

Comment: Try to actually run the code - it works.

Comment: See https://ideone.com/02s6h7 showing it running.

Comment: @roganjosh this is a simplified version of my problem of course. I didn't think I needed to put the calls to `test1` and `test2` explicitly in my post. (But I did try it in my own code). If you like I will add it to here but I think it adds unnecessary clutter.

Comment: @fejfo, demonstrating an actual bug is not clutter. See the [mcve] definition: You need to provide code that's tested to generate the bug you're asking about when run without external setup or dependencies.

Comment: @Charles Duffy okay I will add it, and it works for you? On this site: https://repl.it it doesn't.

Comment: In what Python version is that an error? And since when is "undefined variable" a **syntax** error?

Comment: It works perfectly fine on the repl.it instance/session linked by Daniel Sanchez.

Comment: Also see https://gist.github.com/charles-dyfis-net/e45c75565987b9112fda5b9ebc2714fc showing your code working perfectly when copied/pasted direct from this question into a command-line REPL (Python 3.6.2).

Comment: so after further testing it gives an undefined variable (sometimes) but runs fine. Strange, anyway this solves the problem I was having so thanks guys!

Comment: "Given as undefined variable" -- *what*, specifically, presents that to you? Your IDE? Which one are you using? I'd suggest asking the question to focus specifically on whatever gives you the error (since it isn't coming from Python itself).

Answer (score 2):

Your code is ok, the `undefinded variable` you have there is just a matter of the IDE or helper you are using, seems it cannot capture the `lambda` scope properly.

You can see it running with the same "error" [here](https://repl.it/MQRK/0)
[image]

Comment: A question about a problem that can't be reproduced should be closed, vs answered. Once you set down an answer, that makes it harder for someone else to fix whatever bug in their question that was making it nonreproducible (since in doing so they invalidate your answer).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, i was able to reproduce it, just by copy/pasting the code into the repl.it webpage, their syntax analyzer actually gives that "error", it just disappear after the first run. May I add this as aditional information?

Comment: Hmm. I'm inclined to see at this point if we can encourage the OP to edit the question to specify which tooling is giving the error, rather than simply describing it as coming from "Python 3".

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, yes i think so, I croped an image showing the actual error on the repl.it, wich ill be showing